# ruby on rails/Template is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a very beginner of using ruby on rails. I am trying to build my first full-stack app but I have an error of `Missing template tweets/index`.

Here is my controller:
[controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stzAc.jpg)

Here is my view:
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqn2Q.jpg)

And here is my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  root to: 'tweets#index'  
  get 'tweets', to: 'tweets#index'  
end
```

I am really confused. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tree view of your text editor, it looks like `index.html.erb` isn't inside the `tweets` folder. ie. It is on the same level as that of the `tweets` folder(outside it).

Move it to the `tweets` folder and it should work.